# How to translate 实时新闻定制和推送系统 to English?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word

I once worked on a project called `实时新闻定制和推送系统`. Now someone translated it to English as `Real-time News Ordering and Pushing System`. However I feel strange with the word `Ordering`. I often hear the word `subscribe` when we refer to news. So my question is how can I translate  this project name into English?

Comment: This question seems to be more about the English language than the Chinese language to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real-time news subscription and notification system.

Answer (score 1):

实时新闻定制和推送系统 Real-time news customization and notification service.

Answer (score 0):

`Real-time News Customizing and Pushing System`. Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

```
Customizing Push System and real-time news.
```

Here Push system is like the one sending notification on any mobile device.